# how to insert 1 id and several items with prepared-statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

i have an stored procedure in mysql like this:

```
SET @q1= CONCAT('INSERT INTO tblPermissionRole (IdRole , IdPermission) VALUES (p_IdRole', p_Permission, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q1;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

i want to insert several idPermission with just one idRole, but  with prepared statement i don't know how it's possible. please help me. tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parameter placeholder for the two values

```
SET @q1= 'INSERT INTO tblPermissionRole (IdRole , IdPermission) VALUES (?, ?)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @q1;

set @id := 1;
<some kind of iteration that sets @perm>
  EXECUTE stmt USING @id, @perm;
</some kind ... >

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: you mean i have to separate the iDPermissions  from each other?its overload is not a lot?

Comment: If your stored procedure takes a string of values separated by comma or something you need to split them and do one call per value. There are some ways to do that but none of them are trivial. There is one in this email http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,78793,79230

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert into` .. `select` statement. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx) may help you. the idea is that, you will create a function to split the comma separated parameter value and return a table. You will the table in the insert statement.

Comment: Link to "the following article" please?